# How to force argparse to return a list of strings?

Tags: python, argparse, iterable

i need to use argparse to accept a variable number of strings from command line, but when i pass zero arguments i get a string as result instead of a list of one string.

```
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument(
    '--example',
    nargs='*',
    default='default_value',
    type=str)

args = argparser.parse_args()

for e in args.example:
    print(e)
```

When executing this `python program --example first_arg second_arg` i get the expected result:

```
first_arg
second_arg
```

Even with one argument everything is fine, but executing this `python program` i get:

```
d
e
f
a
u
l
t
_
v
a
l
u
e
```

I'd need to iterate over the list without considering how many elements it has, how could i solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Often it's a good idea to do `print(args)`.  In this case it would show `Namespace(example='default value')`.  The default is assigned as is, not as though it were parsed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the default to a list instead of a string:

```
argparser.add_argument(
    '--example',
    nargs='*',
    default=['default_value'],
    type=str)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your default value is a `str` which can be iterated in python, you can change the default to a list like this:

```py
argparser.add_argument(
    '--example',
    nargs='*',
    default=['default_value'],
    type=str)
```